# como usar um switch dentro de um switch?

Tags: c++, switch

No caso, eu não consigo escolher a opçao do menu selecionar dificuldade, estou fazendo da maneira correta o switch dentro de um switch?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TENTF 5
#define TENTD 3

int main()

{

    char opcao;
    int nome;

    printf("\n\t\t\t-------------------");
    printf("\n\t\t\t   JOGO DA FORCA");
    printf("\n\t\t\t-------------------");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t1 - INICIAR PARTIDA");
    printf("\n\t\t\t2 - CONFIGURAR DIFICULDADE");
    printf("\n\t\t\t3 - SAIR");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tOPCAO DESEJADA:");
    scanf("%c", &opcao);

    switch (opcao)
    {
        case '1':
            printf("\n\n\t\t\tINICIAR PARTIDA");
            break;

        case '2':
            printf("\n\n\t\t\tCONFIGURAR DIFICULDADE"); 
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t-------------------");
            printf("\n\t\t\t   JOGO DA FORCA");
            printf("\n\t\t\t-------------------");
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t F - FACIL");
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t D - DIFICIL");
            printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t V - VOLTAR");
            printf("\n\n\t\t\tOPCAO DESEJADA:");
            scanf("%c", &opcao);
            break;

            switch (opcao)

            {
                case 'F':
                    printf("\n\n\t\t\tCONFIGURAR DIFICULDADE"); 
                    printf("\n\t\t\t-------------------");
                    printf("\n\t\t\t   JOGO DA FORCA");
                    printf("\n\t\t\t-------------------");
                    printf("\n\n\t\t\t F - FACIL*");
                    printf("\n\n\t\t\t D - DIFICIL");
                    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t V - VOLTAR");



                case 'D':
                    printf("\n\n\t\t\tCONFIGURAR DIFICULDADE"); 
                    printf("\n\t\t\t-------------------");
                    printf("\n\t\t\t   JOGO DA FORCA");
                    printf("\n\t\t\t-------------------");
                    printf("\n\n\t\t\t F - FACIL");
                    printf("\n\n\t\t\t D - DIFICIL*");
                    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t V - VOLTAR");
                    break;

                case 'V':

                    printf("\n\t\t\t-------------------");
                    printf("\n\t\t\t   JOGO DA FORCA");
                    printf("\n\t\t\t-------------------");
                    printf("\n\n\t\t\t1 - INICIAR PARTIDA");
                    printf("\n\t\t\t2 - CONFIGURAR DIFICULDADE");
                    printf("\n\t\t\t3 - SAIR");
                    printf("\n\n\t\t\tOPCAO DESEJADA:");
                    scanf("%c", &opcao);
                    break;

                    }




        case '3':

            printf("\n\n\t\t\tSAIR");
            break;

        default:

            printf("\n\n\t\t\tDESCULPE, A OPCAO DIGITADA EH INVALIDA.");
            printf("\n\n\t\t\tOPCAO DESEJADA:");
            scanf("%c", &opcao);
            break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta colocar o segundo switch antes do break.

```
case '2':
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tCONFIGURAR DIFICULDADE"); 
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t-------------------");
    printf("\n\t\t\t   JOGO DA FORCA");
    printf("\n\t\t\t-------------------");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t F - FACIL");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t D - DIFICIL");
    printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t V - VOLTAR");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tOPCAO DESEJADA:");
    scanf("%c", &opcao);


    switch (opcao)
    {
        //cases...
    }

    break;
```

Comment: mesma coisa, ja tinha tentado assim...fiz com if , else ate, mas n deu certo

Comment: rapaz, revisa isso ai direitinho, pois realmente não vejo porque não funcionar dessa forma aqui. Tira esses printf todos, põe algo mais limpo só pra testar.

Comment: Já tentou declarar outra variável para capturar a segunda opção ao invés de usar a mesma?

Answer (score 0):

Se for por esse caminho, logo esse switch vai ser um livro :)

Use funções ao invés de sub-switches.

tipo antes da funcão main defina:

```
void nomeDoQueFazNoSubSwitch() { 
    <coloque aqui o sub-switch>
};
```

e chame-a assim antes do break:?

```
nomeDoQueFazNoSubSwitch();
```

Comment: no caso eu crio uma subrotina, por exemplo: void dificuldade(facil), dentro desse void crio o menu com o facil selecionado. Ai la no int main() no case '2', opcao 'F' eu chamo dificuldade()